# Is there a way to schedule (via application user) calling an URL within the Azure ecosystem?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Here is my scenario:

1. I have an azure website, https://[my app on azure].azurewebsites.us
2. A user of this application wishes to schedule a future action,
   reached via a uri.
3. The application keeps a record of this desire in an Azure SQL database table
   having a "When to act" datetime column and an "Action GUID".

Example: User "bob" will go to the scheduling page in my website
and enter a date and time he wishes the action to execute.
Bob enters 2020-07-11 @ 11:11 am (PDT). 
Upon successful submission a record gets added to the database
with an application generated GUID, "AC5ECA4B-FB4F-44AE-90F9-56931329DB2E"
with a "When to act" value of 2020-07-11 11:11:00.00 -07:00

The action url will an url in my website https://[my app on azure].azurewebsites.us/PerformAction/AC5ECA4B-FB4F-44AE-90F9-56931329DB2E

The SQL database is NOT a Managed Instance.

Would this be possible using SQL CLR? 
I'm thinking not.

Is there a way to do this using an Azure Function and/or Logic App?

Any other ideas?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic apps have a Built-in step Action named "Delay until"

Using this step action in a logic app workflow solved the issue.

Here is what it looks like in the designer:
[image]

Here are further details.
The applications calls the logic app via the HTTP POST URL in the first step
passing in these properties:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "GUID": { // an identifier of the apps schedule
            "type": "string"
        },
        "ID": { // an simpler identifier of the apps schedule
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "MessageID": { // yet another identifier
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "WhenToSend": { // the datetime in UTC format for when to Delay Until
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

Example of payload sent:

[image]

Here is a snippet of the app calling the LA:

```
    newMessageSchedule.MessageScheduleStatuses.Add(new MessageScheduleStatus()
    {
        MessageScheduleStatusID = (int)ApplicationEnums.MessageScheduleStatuses.New
    });
    messageGettingSent.MessageSchedules.Add(newMessageSchedule);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    dynamic schedulePayloadJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        ID = newMessageSchedule.ID,
        GUID = newMessageSchedule.MSGuid,
        MessageID = newMessageSchedule.MessageID,
        WhenToSend = newMessageSchedule.WhenToSend.UtcDateTime
    });
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpContent c = new StringContent(schedulePayloadJSON, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"{dto.SchedulerUri}", c);
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //dynamic httpResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);
        newMessageSchedule.MessageScheduleStatuses.Add(new MessageScheduleStatus()
        {
            MessageScheduleStatusID = (int)ApplicationEnums.MessageScheduleStatuses.Scheduled
        });
        messageGettingSent.MessageSchedules.Add(newMessageSchedule);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

The dto.SchedulerUri is set from an appsettings setting,
TextMessaging:Scheduler and has a value which looks something like this:

```
"https://prod-123.usgovarizona.logic.azure.us:443/workflows/1d8.../triggers/request/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Frequest%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=CJt..."
```

Once the "Delay Until" time occurs, the LA calls back into the app w/ the IDs:

[image]

The controller action performs all the things.

Voila
/vwäˈlä/

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you are putting together is a simple polling pattern.  You need a function that will poll your data store every x minutes(or seconds) (function cron expression => * */x * * * *).  It would then check that the current time is on or about to be exceeded by the stored time.  If this is the case, it could then make your call.  Don't forget to write back to the data store the success or failure of the call.  If there are multiple steps, you should record where in the full life-cycle that command is.  This way you can take the appropriate action.

To make your function app better, I would introduce a message queue (Azure Storage Queue) that receives the  parts required to make the call.  Then have a function (triggered by the messages on the queue) to send your web call.  This way each function is operating separately from each other.

To reduce the need to poll all of the records, you could filter your records with SQL to be "between" certain timestamps guided by the current time of the the polling function.

If you need more clarity, leave comments and I'll try to provide more context.

Store or convert times to UTC to avoid timezone mismatches.

Comment: thanks daviesdoesit  I'll see what I can come up with. I guess I was trying to avoid a polling scenario since we know already know when the action should occur.  Yes, I'll have a status column on my records so we know they are processed.  Yes on the date times. I recently converted all my datetime2 columns to datetimeoffset.

Comment: In my opinion, there will always be a polling mechanism.  In traditional, on-prem, database solutions you could have scheduled tasks on the OS or use SQL Server's built-in features.  The Cloud challenges these previous approaches.  What if there is no OS?  Consider a no-Sql option like CosmosDB.  Those do not offer the polling of on-prem.  However, you get to decide how and when the data is polled. If most of your entries are at a certain time frame (M-F 9-5) you could have one function poll every 5 seconds during the work day and another function (running less often) at night.